# get big amount of data from flutter firebase

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart

i am working on a social media application and i want to show the user posts of other followed user , i have an idea to put the link of all the posts of other user together and use them in a futurebuild statement, but the problem is if we have more than 1000 posts for example , it could take a while to retrieve all the data and then show it to the user,(note : i am useing pageView builder the display each post alone), my question is , how can we make the program to display about 10 posts and then in the background it could still work on the other posts , so the user dont have to wait untill all posts are retrieved. thank your for your attention !!

Comment: If you're using Firestore, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors. If you're using the Realtime Database, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+pagination

Comment: oh thank you thats exactly what i am looking for